# How to use app.use selectively in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

Say I have

**app.get('/user/:id', /* some function */)**

and

**app.delete('/user/:id', /* some function */)**

I want to add **app.use('/user/:id'** to do certain stuff, but that certain stuff needs to be done only for delete not for get.

How do I make app.use execute for delete but not for get

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `request.method` and check if it is equal to `'DELETE'`.

```
app.use('/user/:id', function(request, result){ 
    if(request.method === 'DELETE) { // Do stuff for delete } 
});
```